# Provide full access over terminal for child, while it alive

Tags: terminal, fork, parent-child, dup2

I use fork() in order to exec some another program, for example "vim" or "man bash". But, at that moment I lost control, I can't print anything in vim or scroll or quite.

So, my question: how give child full access over terminal(input/output) and get it back for parent after child death?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, my question: how give child full access over terminal(input/output) and get it back for parent after child death?

[`waitpid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/waitpid) and `SIGCHLD` are mechanisms for knowing when a child process has finished.  The functions [`tcgetpgrp(fd)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetpgrp) and [`tcsetpgrp(fd,pgrp)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetpgrp) and `ctermid()` can be used to place a program in the *foreground* of a terminal.

Otherwise, the information in [`tcsetpgrp()` in 'C'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341220/how-do-i-get-tcsetpgrp-to-work-in-c) is probably instructive.