# send background process to foreground

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash

A c++ program of mine calls fork() and the child immediately executes another program. I have to put interact with the child, but terminate its parent simultaneously because its executable will be replaced. I somehow need to get the orphan back into the foreground so that I may interact with it via the bash - I am currently only getting its output. So I either need to send the parent to the background, the child to the foreground and then terminate the parent, or send the child to the background immediately when the parent terminates.

To my knowledge, I must set the child to be process group leader before its parent terminates. 
With generous borrowing from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341220/how-do-i-get-tcsetpgrp-to-work-in-c), I arrived at the following testing ground (note, this is not the full program - it just outlines the procedure):

```
int main(int argc, char *argcv[])

printf("%i\n", argc);
printf("\nhello, I am %i\n", getpid());
printf("parent is %i\n", getppid());
printf("process leader is %i\n", getsid(getpid()));
int pgrp;
std::stringstream pidstream;
pidstream << tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO);
pidstream >> pgrp;
printf("foreground process group ID %i\n", pgrp);

if(argc==1)
{
    int child = fork();
    if(!child) {execl("./nameofthisprogram","nameofthisprogram", "foo", NULL);}
    else
    {
        signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
        usleep(1000*1000*1);
        tcsetpgrp(0, child);
        tcsetpgrp(1, child);

        std::stringstream pidstream2;
        pidstream2 << tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO);
        pidstream2 >> pgrp;
        printf("foreground process group ID %i\n", pgrp);
        usleep(1000*1000*3);
        return 0;           
    }
}
// signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN); unnecessary

int input;
int input2;

printf("write something\n");
std::cin >> input;
printf("%i\n", input);
usleep(1000*1000*3);
printf("%i\n", input);

printf("write something else\n");
std::cin >> input2;
usleep(1000*1000*3);
printf("%i\n", input2);

return 0;
```

With the above code, the parent dies after I get prompted for the first input. If I then delay my answer beyond the parent's death, it picks up the first input character and prints it again. For input2, the program does not wait for my input.
So it seems that after the first character, input is entirely terminated.
Am I approaching this fundamentally wrong, or is it simply a matter of reassigning a few more ids and altering some signals?

Comment: foreground? background? what do you mean?

Comment: Why do you need the `fork`? It looks like you've only got one process that's actually doing anything; you can just `execl` it directly without forking . . .

Comment: @ruakh this program is just an outline of a subprocess in the real program - the child eventually removes the executable of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things wrong here.

1. You're never putting the child process in its own process group; therefore, it remains in the original one and is therefore in the foreground *along with the parent*.
2. You're calling `tcsetpgrp()` twice; it only needs to be called once. Assuming no redirection, stdin and stdout both refer to the terminal and therefore either call would do.

> With the above code, the parent dies after I get prompted for the first input. If I then delay my answer beyond the parent's death, it picks up the first input character and prints it again. For input2, the program does not wait for my input. So it seems that after the first character, input is entirely terminated.

What you're observing here is a direct consequence of `1.`: since both processes are in the foreground, they're both racing to read from stdin and the outcome is undefined.

> I somehow need to get the orphan back into the foreground so that I may interact with it via the bash - I am currently only getting its output.

From what I understand, you would expect to be interacting with the exec'ed child after the `fork()/exec()`. For that to happen, the child needs to be in its own process group, and needs to be put in the foreground.

```
int child = fork();
signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
if (!child) {
  setpgid(0, 0); // Put in its own process group
  tcsetpgrp(0, getpgrp()); // Avoid race condition where exec'd program would still be in the background and would try to read from the terminal
  execl("./nameofthisprogram","nameofthisprogram", "foo", NULL);
} else {
  setpgid(child, child); // Either setpgid call will succeed, depending on how the processes are scheduled.
  tcsetpgrp(0, child); // Move child to foreground
}
```

Notice that we call the `setpgid()/tcsetpgrp()` pair in both the parent and the child. We do so because we don't know which will be scheduled first, and we want to avoid the race condition where the exec'ed program would attempt to read from stdin (and therefore receive a SIGTTIN which would stop the process) before the parent has had time to put it in the foreground. We also ignore SIGTTOU because we know that either the child or the parent will receive one with the calls to `tcsetpgrp()`.