# How can I put my own shell into foreground after waitpid call?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am trying make my own shell for my school homework, after the sucessfull fork call, I want to put pid which comes from fork() function into foreground and then I want to put my own shell into background. Then after the waitpid function, I need to my own shell into foreground again. For this I think like this:

```
        if(tcsetpgrp(0, getpgid(pid))!=0)
        perror("Foreground error: ");

        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

        if(tcsetpgrp(0, getpgid(shellpid))!=0)
        perror("Foreground error: ");}
```

But after new process finishes, the linux shell stops my own shell.
For instance, ls command is the new process in the picture.
[Please look at here: for terminal screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ4LE.png)

Comment: Related: [How do I get tcsetpgrp() to work in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341220/how-do-i-get-tcsetpgrp-to-work-in-c). Your shell will stop when it's the background process and tries to change the tty's pgrp. Fix is to (temporarily) ignore SIGTTOU.

Comment: Thank you for your help adding "signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);" before tcsetpgrp solved my problem. However, I need to use Ctrl+Z command to stop process, so I can't do that when I ignore it.

Comment: Control-Z sends a SIGTSTP signal to the foreground process group. It has a similar effect as SIGTTOU, but they're different signals. Is adding the line of code that ignores SIGTTOU preventing Control-Z from working correctly?

Comment: I have used sigprocmask to ignore SIGTTOU temporarily, but when I press the Ctrl-Z it writes just ^Z not stop the current process, but Ctrl-C works well. For example when I write >>cat then press the Ctrl-C it terminates and turns my own shell. I am really confused

Comment: Before you added the sigprocmask call, did Control-Z work?

Comment: Not actually it stops the my own shell turns back the linux shell, but I need to stop process and turn back to my own shell to take next command

Comment: Can you ask that as a new question? If you can, please include all the code in the parent and child that does any setpgid, tcsetgrp, fork, waitpid, and exec* calls.

Answer (score 1):

adding "signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);" before tcsetpgrp solved my problem. – Ali Can Üstünel