# Why is STDIN not propagated to child process of different process group?

Tags: c, linux, stdin

Below is the source of a program that executes `cat`:

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (!pid) {
    // create a new process group
    setpgid(0, 0);

    execlp("cat", "cat", NULL);
  }

  pid_t reaped = wait(NULL);
  printf("reaped PID = %d\n", (int) reaped);
  return 0;
}
```

Note the call to `setpgid(0, 0)`.

When run in a shell (either `sh` or `bash`), I expected:

1. the parent to spawn a child process of `cat`, and
2. the child to start interacting with the terminal.

However, what happens is:

1. the parent spawns `cat` with no problem, but
2. the child is *stopped* (with process state code `T` in `ps`), and
3. the child accepts no input from the terminal, and
4. the child does not respond to any of `SIGINT`, `SIGSTOP` or `SIGQUIT`, only to be killed by `SIGKILL`.

When the call to `setpgid()` is commented out, everything is as expected.

I suspect the behavior is caused by:

- the child `cat` is trying to read stdin and is waiting (thus stopped), but
- the input to the terminal is first passed to `bash`, and then to the program above, however not to the `cat`, possibly because `bash` does not recognize its grandchildren, `cat`, because of its different process group.

Of course, removing `setpgid()` call is the simplest solution. Unfortunately there are some reasons; mainly to intercept some signals (such as SIGINT or SIGSTOP) in the parent. In other words, a `<Ctrl-C>` should not kill the `cat` but somehow signal the program above. (There are no signal handlers in the program above, yes, for illustrative purpose.)

I'd like to ask:

1. Is this correct?
2. Whether it is or not, how can I have `cat` to receive inputs from stdin?

Comment: There seems to be an issue.  If I'm not mistaken, signals from the terminal are sent to the foreground process group, that is the one which is accepting output and input.  Here you seem to want to decouple the two, that does not fit my understanding  (which is not perfect, I'd have expected at least to be able to use `tcsetpgrp` with your program to start a new group and change the foreground process group to that group but I was wrong).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on Ubuntu 19.04. I run the program as `./program < inputfile` and it prints the contents of `inputfile`. When I run it with `strace` as `strace -f ./program < inputfile` I can see that it executes `/usr/bin/cat` and that `cat` reads the input file from stdin and writes the data to stdout.

Comment: @AProgrammer You are right! `tcsetpgrp` was what I needed. Thank you for letting me know. About `tcsetpgrp` not working one can refer to [another answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341220/how-do-i-get-tcsetpgrp-to-work-in-c).

Comment: @Namnamseo, thanks.  I'll have to dig into that answer to complete my understanding.  If your problem is solved, I suggest you to write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the foreground process group (which assumes all STDIN) can be changed via `tcsetpgrp()`.

The function may as well be called from the child. Otherwise the parent will have to wait for the child to do a successful `setpgid()` call and a concurrency issue will happen.

However, as described in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341220/how-do-i-get-tcsetpgrp-to-work-in-c), when the child (which is not yet foreground) call `tcsetpgrp`, it will get a signal of SIGTTOU, according to the manual of `tcsetpgrp`. The default action for SIGTTOU is to stop the process, and this should be manually ignored.

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  // ignore SIGTTOU
  signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);

  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (!pid) {
    // create a new process group
    setpgid(0, 0);
    tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, getpgid(0));

    execlp("cat", "cat", NULL);
  }

  pid_t reaped = wait(NULL);
  printf("reaped PID = %d\n", (int) reaped);
  return 0;
}
```

Now the underlying `cat` starts to interact with the terminal, and the problem is solved.

```
uuu@hhh:~$ ./a
sajkfla
sajkfla
wjkelfaw
wjkelfaw
reaped PID = 774
uuu@hhh:~$ ./a
```